# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function - immer redux reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, immer.js

I am using Immer with redux reducer and I got this warning

```
Expected to return a value at the end of the arrow function
```

How can I fix it?

my reducer looks like :

```
export const optionReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: optionActionTypes
) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case OPTION_GETALL_SUCCESS: {
        draft.data = action.payload;
        break;
      }
      default:
        return draft;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the `switch` branches you perfrom `break` while in the other you do `return`. You should either return in both, or break in both and return at the end of the function

```
export const optionReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: optionActionTypes
) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case OPTION_GETALL_SUCCESS: {
        draft.data = action.payload;
        return draft;
      }
      default:
        return draft;
    }
  });
```